# About `fill-paragraph` in `markdown-mode`

Tags: fill-paragraph, sentences

I have a buffer on `markdown-mode` with the following contents.

```
        10         20        30        40        50        60        70

- a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a


- A aaaaaa aa aa aaaaaaa. Aaa aaaa aaaaaa a
  aaaaaaaaaa. Aaaaaa-a. (progn (set-fill-column 70) (fill-paragraph))
```

If I place the cursor after the last parenthesis and running `eval-last-sexp`, nothing changes. I expected something like the following

```
        10         20        30        40        50        60        70

- a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a


- A aaaaaa aa aa aaaaaaa. Aaa aaaa aaaaaa a aaaaaaaaaa. Aaaaaa-a.
  (progn (set-fill-column 70) (fill-paragraph))
```

Why does this happen? Same happens if I am on `text-mode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph is already filled.

If you add another `SPC` char after the period (`.`) then you see the paragraph filled differently.  Or if you set variable (option) `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` then you'll also see it filled differently.

Comment: Thank you @Drew. I still don't understand why it is already filled, though.

Comment: It already has newline chars at the line ends, and all of the lines are, in effect, filled to the auto-fill max length.  So no need to change the line lengths.